# Unable to click a button in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver

I'm facing a tough time clicking a button from Selenium.

Here's the DOM: http://pasteboard.co/GHIjMd6.png

I've declared the button WebElement this way using Xpath (a valid Xpath that returns one node as per Firepath):

```
WebElement send_this_msg_btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='mp-button-content'][.='Send This Message']"));
```

I've tried clicking the said button with `send_this_msg_btn` Xpath in below mentioned ways, but none of them work for me.

WebDriver's `click()` method : `send_this_msg_btn.click()`

JavaScriptExecutor:

```
JavaScriptExecutor jse = (JavaScriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", send_this_msg_btn);
```

Actions class:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(send_this_msg_btn);
actions.click();
actions.build().perform();
```

I also checked if the button is inside a frame/iframe, but that's not the case either.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Kapil Please check this link: https://pasteboard.co/GHIjMd6.png

Comment: I get NoSuchElementException in all cases.

Comment: Probably your xpath is incorrect. Try with - `WebElement send_this_msg_btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='mp-button-content' and contains(.,'Send This Message')]` and lets see if it works.

Comment: From the above html code. this `Send This Message` does not look like a button.

Comment: Try driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:contains('Send This Message')")).click();

Comment: @SaiPawan, Can you explain me where did you see this `Send This Message` button?

Comment: Even if it is not a button, We can click on div using selenium if it is clickable.

Comment: @SaiPawan With the cssSelector approach you mentioned, I get "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
".

Comment: @AkshayMaldhure - did you try my comment?

Comment: Yes, I tried with that xpath. No luck! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the xpath to `.//mp-button[@class='mp-button-primary submit_button']` resolved the issue, but I'm not sure if this should be the accepted answer since I'm not sure if it's a fragile xpath. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

Try to click on the parent button

```
xpath = "//*[@class='mp-button-content'][.='Send This Message']/.."
```

or it's parent

```
xpath = "//*[@class='mp-button-content'][.='Send This Message']/../.."
```

and use the explicit wait until element is clickable.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement elem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)));
elem.click();
```

Comment: None of these work. I get `NoSuchElementException` in both the cases.

Comment: then you need to use explicit wait with both xpath I suggested. also update your question with exception/error you are getting. if you are not getting any error then mention that as well.

Comment: I tried using explicit wait too with the xpaths you mentioned, I get this: "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable".

Comment: Which `ExpectedCondition` do you suggest to use?

Comment: That's what I had tried (tried with 20 seconds instead of 30), but still no luck!

Comment: how about clicking using javascript on one of the xpath i suggsted?

Comment: Tried that too:
`jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", send_this_msg_btn);`
Getting "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='mp-button-content'][.='Send This Message']/.."}".

Comment: then use explicit wait before this action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153018/discussion-between-akshay-maldhure-and-gaurang-shah).